# Install gcc on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, gcc

When I try to install gcc on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server with `apt-get install gcc`, I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc : Depends: cpp (>= 4:4.6.1-2ubuntu5) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: gcc-4.6 (>= 4.6.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                   libc-dev
```

When I delve deeper (i.e. try to `apt-get install gcc-4.6`), I get:

```
 gcc-4.6 : Depends: gcc-4.6-base (= 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) but 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
           Depends: cpp-4.6 (= 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgomp1 (>= 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libquadmath0 (>= 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: libc6-dev (>= 2.13-0ubuntu6) but it is not going to be installed
```

So when I try to install `gcc-4.6=4.6.1-9ubuntu3` I get a list of 366 packages to remove (including e.g. `apt`). Which is craziness.

This is an essentially vanilla installation of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server (i.e. I installed nginx, python-flup, python-yaml, rsync, python-pkg-resources, lsof, fontconfig, iptables, ufw, scons, and grc).

It is very surprising to me that I cannot install gcc, so I am somewhat confused as to why attempting to install gcc fails. The only apparent fix would seem to be uninstalling 366 packages, many of which are central to the operation of Ubuntu.

Something doesn't add up, and I would be very grateful for assistance.

**EDIT** The above is with the latest packages of course, having used `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade` before attempting the above. Sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Have you tried sudo apt-get update

Answer (score 92, accepted):

There's a metapackage called `build-essential` which should install the compiler and a bunch of related/needed packages:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

The suggestion to first do `sudo apt-get update` is sound, this will update package lists and all versions should match nicely.

That is, however, if you didn't modify your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file manually. If so, then maybe some of the changes you made or repositories you added contain conflicting packages which cause the problems you see. If that's the case, please look at the file and fix the troublesome entries. Of course, if you want help doing so, you can post your `sources.list` file (or any fragments in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`) and maybe someone can help you fix them.

Comment: The problem was an errant reference to oneric in the `sources.list`. When I removed this reference, everything installed naturally. Great suggestion to look in `sources.list` for the problem - Thanks - much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try to keep going deeper:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.6-base cpp-4.6 libgomp1 libquadmath0 libc6-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

First write the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then try:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

I did this and it worked! You should also try it.

If it does not works then:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Then try. I hope it will work!

Comment: Hi Master Programmer, welcome to askubuntu! First, when composing an answer, use the formatting tools - especially block format - to make the answer easier to follow. Secondly, pretty much the exact some answer had already been given.  Be invited to [take the tour](http://askubuntu.com/tour) and learn how to write good answers.

Comment: Secondly, your answer does not substantially improve upon other answers which already exist.  (It doesn't qualify as "Not an Answer", but it does get this comment)